# Android: Read file on external storage without user interactions

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage

Short summary:
Reading a public accessible file on Android 11 without using anything that requires user interactions (e.g.g picking file or enable permissions).

Hi,

I want to read a file from the external storage on my Android device (for example located in the DOCUMENTS or DOWNLOADS directory).

Is there a way to access it without using the file picker workflow using [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file) / [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory)?

The device I'm using is running Android 11.

I want to prevent the file picker because I want to automate reading of a file located on the external storage with as few as possible user interactions.

I'vw tried to use use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to get access to files on external storage but still get exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/filetoread.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

when I try to read the file with this code when the file `filetoread.txt` is located in `Downloads` directory:

```
File downloadsDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File fileToRead = new File(downloadsDir, "filetoread.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToRead)); // <- here the FileNotFoundException is thrown
```

When I use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission it works without exception. But I want to prevent using this permission, since I want only read access to one file and it also needs user interactions to enable this permission.

Would be very happy if someone could help me with this one. :)

Comment: Not possible on Android 11+ devices.

Comment: Where is the file coming from? Is it created by your app?

Comment: @blackapps Ok thanks, then at least I don‘t have to search more.

Comment: @SergeiKozelko The files are not created by the app. Just files copied with file transfer from my computer or downloaded files.